# Higher order versions of Itô isometry

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Given a (one-dimensional) stochastic process $X_t$ and Wiener process $W_t$, the Itô isometry says that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\left[\int_0^TX_tdW_t\right]^2\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^T X_t^2 dt\right).
$$
Is there a similar (or different!) trick to computing
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\left[\int_0^TX_tdW_t\right]^n\right),
$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 3}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned here [4th moment of a Wiener stochastic integral with Ito isometry property?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699531/4th-moment-of-a-wiener-stochastic-integral-with-ito-isometry-property/4753013#4753013), one can use that Hermite polynomials are martingales to at least estimate them.

[image]

In case the link dies, the proof simply uses that Hermite polynomials $H_{2m}(x,t)$ of Itô integrals are martingales and that the leading coefficient is $x^{2m}$.