# 4th moment of a Wiener stochastic integral with Ito isometry property?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, moment-generating-functions, isometry

Suppose we have a Wiener stochastic integral
$$\int_{t-h}^t f(r_v) d W_v, \tag{1}$$
It is well known that, by the Ito isometry property,
$$\mathbb E \left [\left(\int_{t-h}^t f(r_v) d W_v\right)^2 \bigg | \mathcal F_{t-h}\right] = \int_{t-h}^t \mathbb E[f(r_v)^2|\mathcal F_{t-h}] d v.$$

I am wondering how to extend this result to  fourth conditional moments in general
$$\mathbb E \left[\left(\int_{t-h}^t f(r_v) d W_v\right)^4 \bigg | \mathcal F_{t-h}\right].$$

---

There is an answer to a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606138/4th-moment-of-a-wiener-stochastic-integral) that implies:
$$
\mathbb E \left[\left(\int_{t-h}^t f(r_v) d W_v\right)^4 \bigg| \mathcal F_{t-h}\right] = 3 \left[\int_{t-h}^t \mathbb E[f(r_v)^2 |\mathcal F_{t-h}] d v\right]^2 \tag{2}
$$

However, it seems that the answer relies on the fact that $\mathbb E (Y^4) = 3 (\sigma^2)^2$ for any $Y \sim N(0,\sigma^2).$

So my question goes, how can I compute the conditional fourth moment of (1) when $\int_{t-h}^t f(r_v) d W_v$ is not normally distributed? Should I expect result (2)?

---

An example with $f(x) = x$ would be computing  $$\mathbb E \left[ \left(\int_{t-h}^t r_v d W_v\right)^4 \bigg | \mathcal F_{t-h} \right]$$
given, e.g. $$d r_{t} = \mu(r_t) d t + \eta \sqrt{r_t} d W_t.$$

Thank you.

Comment: I think that in general, you need to do do a case-by-case analysis. So for instance with your process $r_t$, start by applying Itô's lemma to $\left(\int_{t-h}^t r_v d W_v\right)^4$ and see if you can compute the expectations of the terms you get.

Comment: @StratosFair so you are not awear of any general approach to end up with something like:  $h\left(\int_{t-h}^t \mathbb E[g(r_v) |\mathcal F_{t-h}] d v\right)$, where $h(\bullet)$ $g(\bullet)$ are some functions.

Comment: Indeed, I am not aware of such a result, sorry. In the specific example you give though I think the "brute force" approach will work, although it will probably be quite tedious.

Comment: The product of two integrals is the integral over the square with two independent variables. with Itos rule, that identical dW^2 -> dt, so one simply has to identify in a product of four  dW .. dW all identical pairs.

Answer (score 1):

This falls into studying multiple iterated Wiener integrals (see Wiener chaos). Here one can at least get an upper bound. As mentioned in ["Notes on the Itô Calculus"](http://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/385/ItoIntegral.pdf) by Steven P. Lalley

[image]

and so for $m=2$ we get

$$E\left(\int f dW\right)^{4}\leq c_{2}E\left[\left(\int f^{2} dW\right)^{2}\right]^{2}=c_{2}\left(\int Ef^{2} ds\right)^{2}.$$

In case the link dies, the proof simply uses that Hermite polynomials $H_{2m}(x,t)$ of Itô integrals are martingales and that the leading coefficient is $x^{2m}$.